# vs2008 c#: Facebook.rest.api how to use it to get friends list?

Tags: c#, facebook

How to make further progress from here? What would be next step to get friends list?

```
       string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Key"];
        string APISecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Secret"];

        Facebook.Session.ConnectSession connectsession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(APIKey, APISecret);
        Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(connectsession);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're really close.  All that is left to do is call the GetLists method in the Friends namespace.

```
var friends = api.Friends.GetLists();
foreach (var friend in friends)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(friend.name);
}
```

[Here's the link to the REST api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/).  It should help you find other functions.  Another way is to just use visual studios IntelliSense.  Type api. and visual studios should give you a list you can navigate through.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the application: [Fishbowl](http://www.fishbowlclient.com/) It is a WPF Reference app for Facebook that has full source code.  It may help you with many facebook items.

Comment: I just downloaded the source code. Its huge. I dont know where to start.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the code either but the Contigo project is the Key.  It has a facebookservice and a facebookwebapi class that seem to be the main entry points into the facebook service.  I will admit I have not used this but I know it pulls the data you are asking for.  Just a matter of disecting it.  facebookwebapi I believe is the one you might want to focus on though.