# How to get friends list from facebook? (Desktop application)

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-c#-sdk

As per this link [code from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986461/vs2008-c-facebook-rest-api-how-to-use-it-to-get-friends-list) i have try this code for getting 
friendslist but after login i got this error **"requires valid signature"**

```
string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Key"];
string APISecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Secret"];

Facebook.Session.ConnectSession connectsession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(APIKey, APISecret);
        Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(connectsession);
        var friends = api.Friends.GetLists();
        foreach (var friend in friends)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(friend.name);
        }
```

guide me to find out the solution

Thanks
ash

Comment: Why do you have the line `Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(connectsession);` twice?

Comment: sorry now i edited, when i paste here twice i paste

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with a new application, you should definitely use the Graph API and not the old Rest API. The Rest API has been deprecated for quite a while now and there is no guarantee how much longer Facebook will support it.

For an example on using the Graph API try http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

You can obtain the friends list by making a request to `me/friends`

You can test other requests using the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).